# Files does not write into correct partition

Tags: linux, files, raspberry-pi

I created partitions using `fdisk` and the partitions will automatically attached during startup as I registered them in `/etc/fstab` as shown:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p4  /mnt/mmcblk0p4  ext4    defaults        0       0
```

When i type in `df -h` :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       3.6G  3.1G  279M  92% /
devtmpfs        433M     0  433M   0% /dev
tmpfs           438M     0  438M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           438M   19M  419M   5% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           438M     0  438M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   44M   23M   21M  53% /boot
/dev/mmcblk0p4  3.6G  1.8G  1.6G  53% /mnt/mmcblk0p4
```

I have a script to write JSON file into `/mnt/mmcblk0p4/json/` directory using `cronjob` every minute.

When i unmount using `sudo umount -l /mnt/mmcblk0p4` I found out that some JSON files are exist exactly same directory of `/mnt/mmcblk0p4/json/` , and the JSON files are using `/` spaces but not `/mnt/mmcblk0p4` 's.

I seems can't find any related article regarding to this situation. I believed that the JSON files are write into the root partition during startup when the `/mnt/mmcblk0p4` partition is still not yet mounted properly.

**My Questions:**

How can I prevent this from happening?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mountpoint` to check if `/mnt/mmcblk0p4` is a mount point and take the appropriate action in your script (mount, wait, ...).

For example, this will echo "Yes" if `/mnt/mmcblk0p4` is a mountpoint:

```
$ mountpoint /mnt/mmcblk0p4 && echo "Yes"
```

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo. it's works!